# how to pass image from view controller to tab bar with segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am at a loss as to how to pass a selected image in one view controller to a tab bar controller using a segue, i keep on getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance ...". Here is my prepare for segue in a ViewController3 :

```
 if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"tabbarGo"]) {

    UITabBarController *tabar=segue.destinationViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = [tabar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    ViewController5 *fifthView=[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    fifthView.theImage = selectedImage.image;

    [tabar setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

i have imported ViewController5 into ViewController3 as 5 is the tab bar controller and the m file for viewcontroller5 is as follows :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController5.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"
@interface ViewController5 ()
@end

@implementation ViewController5

@synthesize theImage;
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[_imageView setImage:theImage];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

I do not understand what i am doing wrong and have gone through most of the posts, or should i go through a "NSUserDefaults *prefs" approach to this ?
Any help appreciated and thanks.

Comment: Post the full message of the exception you're getting

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setTheImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7902ece0

Comment: That means the view controller that you think is your `ViewController5` is actually a navigation controller (probably the one that your view controller is embedded in). So you have a tab bar with a navigation controller in it which has another navigation controller in it. Either take the first view controller of that inner navigation controller assuming it is your `ViewController5` or remove that extra navigation controller from your storyboard if it isn't necessary.

Comment: ok will give it a try and let you know....thank you.

Comment: ok...took out the navigation controllers or "unembedded them" and indeed i can travel from 3 to 5 but i don't have my selected image in the tab bar and on top of that as soon as i identify the segue in storyboard as the one in the prepare for segue it crashes and i no longer arrive at viewcontroller5....i get an "unrecognised selector" error again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it to work to send an image to a tab bar with navigation controller by adding one line of code, i was forgetting to specify the NSString value of the segue so here is the final full code for "prepare for segue" :

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSString * segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
 UITabBarController *tabar=segue.destinationViewController;
UINavigationController *navController = [tabar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
ViewController5 *fifthView=[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
fifthView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
[tabar setSelectedIndex:1];        
}
```